# How to ask for CMMotionActivityManager permissions

Tags: ios, swift

I have a functionality on my App that needs to track the user's activity. After reading the `Core Motion` documentation I discovered that `CMMotionActivityManager` handles this for me.

For now I have the following code, which checks if the user have permissions:

```
guard CMMotionActivityManager.isActivityAvailable() else {
    showErrorAlert(title: "Error", message: "Your phone don't support this functionality due to hardware limitation.")
    return
}

guard CMMotionActivityManager.authorizationStatus() == .authorized || CMMotionActivityManager.authorizationStatus() == .notDetermined else {
    showErrorAlert(title: "Error", message: "Motion's permission is required to run this functionality. Enable it in your phone settings.")
    return
}

activityManager.startActivityUpdates(to: OperationQueue.main) { [weak self] (activity: CMMotionActivity?) in
    self?.currentActivity = activity
}
```

Currently I have the following problem, `activityManager.startActivityUpdates` asks for permission in an async manner, however it doesn't have an callback or an error for when the user does not accept the permission.

How should I handle the case that the user does not accept the permission?